# Class Table Inheritance in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class-table-inheritance

I'm currently working on a Rails 3 application that looks like it might need to use Class Table Inheritance for a couple of models.

A simplified example of what's going on is this.

I have a class called Person with general attributes like name, email, password which are common to all types of people in the application and used for authentication.

There are two subclasses to Person (or two types of people...), Driver and Passenger. Both of these subclasses share the generic attributes of Person but then have specific additional attributes which are unique to themselves. (for example a Driver can have many Vehicles and Licenses but a Passenger would not)

How would I implement CTI for this kind of situation? I've been looking at an example provided here:

http://rhnh.net/2010/08/15/class-table-inheritance-and-eager-loading

But it doesn't speculate on how to access the common attributes of a Person from a Driver or Passenger object and I'm a bit confused by that.

In particular, what I'd like to know is:

If I'm updating the attributes of a Driver, how can I easily access and update the relevant attributes on the parent people table? Do I have to hook into an after_save callback and separate out which attribute update goes where? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I should add that this is a simplified example of what's actually going on in my app. I'm sure that I need to implement Class Table Inheritance in my situation, Single Table Inheritance would not be the best way.

Comment: I put a comment on the blog I referred to in my question and the author kindly provided an example of one way to do this: http://rhnh.net/2010/08/17/updating-class-table-inheritance-tables (You rock Xavier!)

Answer (score 7):

Also there is a plugin 'acts_as_relation' to do this,
https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation/

in your case the code will be this:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as :person
end

class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :person
end
```

Don't forget to add `person_type` and `person_id` columns to `persons` table.
Now both Drive and Passenger inherit Person attributes, validations and methods.

Answer (score 5):

why not using Single Table Inheritance? for example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   # some common code here
end

class Driver < Person
   # Driver code
end

class Passenger < Person
   # Passenger code
end
```

in this way you'll have a common class Person, plus two specific classes derived from it

Comment: Note: the OP asked about how to use Class Table Inheritance, not Single Table Inheritance.

Comment: sometimes people ask for the incorrect question, I just answered a possible solution to his problem.

Comment: Then it should be suggested as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the class table inheritance plugin and it working well, http://github.com/brunofrank/class-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check out the plugin!

Comment: Not the best solution, cause not working fine with postgres (ie, don't use this if you intend to use heroku with postgres)

Answer (score 2):

I recently forked a promising project to implement multiple table inheritance and class inheritance in Rails. I have spent a few days subjecting it to rapid development, fixes, commenting and documentation and have re-released it as CITIER (Class Inheritance and Table Inheritance Embeddings for Rails).

I think you could potentially combine it with the answers above?

Consider giving it a look: http://peterhamilton.github.com/citier

I looked at solutions like the class-table-inheritance repo, but this is much cleaner and more logical IMO.

It also supports the main SQL languages SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL and probably more but I haven;t tested them.

Comment: This gem seems to be the most feature complete of the three. May I ask if you have looked into performance comparison? And also integration with Sunspot (since db views are used)?

Comment: Works great... but we ran into lots of problem with heroku. It didn't like the table views, especially when pushing/pulling the db. Ended up removing it.