# How do you get the type when using Table Per Type inheritance in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of classes that look like this:

```
Person {
    id(PK)
    first_name string
    last_name string
}

class Employee {
    person_id(FK)
    job_description string
}

class Student {
    person_id(FK)
    school_name string
}
```

If I had a large list of People, how could I figure out what type each of them are without having to do

```
Student.where(person_id = person.id).any?
```

and

```
Employee.where(person_id = person.id).any?
```

for every "person" in the list?

I need to do a similar operation very often, so would Single Table Inheritance be a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to implement is [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).

(See earlier questions. eg. ["Class Table Inheritance in Rails 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499215/class-table-inheritance-in-rails-3))

There are various gems trying to implement this,
and they each have their own opinions.

Fundamentally if all you know is the "person_id" then you will always need to look up the other tables to find which class it is.

The simplest way you can do this without changing anything fundamental is to use rails' `has_one` to create a cached relation between the two tables.

```
class Person
  has_one :employee_details, class_name: "Employee"
  has_one :student_details, class_name: "Student"

  def employee?
    employee_details.present?
  end

  def student?
    student_details.present?
  end
end
```

Importantly a Person can be both an employee and a student.

If that is not the case, then I suggest you look at Rails' Single Table Inheritance, or consider another way of implementing the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Ruby on Rails (ActiveRecord)

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :students
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :person 
end

class Student
  belongs_to :person
end

Person.find(person_id).students.any?
Person.find(person_id).employees.any?

Also, for the record, I am just answering the question as you phrased it.  I think a better design would be to have a class called (Role) and have Employee and Student extend from that so you could have a many to many association to Role so a person could be both a student(s) and an employee(s) which is entirely possible

Comment: Person.find(person_id).students.any? still runs an SQL query for each person so that's not good.

I like your suggestion of having Roles though

Comment: That's not true, It will find the person you are looking for with exactly one query.  Please see for yourself

Comment: I meant that If I had a list of people, and wanted to find out what type they each belonged to, I would still need to run 2 Queries per person.

Comment: I think I will try to implement Roles though